# Dynamically Display Multiple Currency Prices for Different Locales On Same Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am trying to display different prices for a single product on a generic /eu/ webpage. The prices are fixed so I am hoping this can be done using a simple query but I am very new to JS/JQuery.

Currently the price is displayed in div with the class `price-block`
and users can toggle their locale with a `data-locale="{country code}"` div.

Using these two IDs, can I create a script that says e.g. `data-locale="UK"` then price is £1000?

I think I need to be looking into "if this selected, var equals this value" solutions - any help much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can use switch/cases https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: key/val object might be better for this, e.g. `{"UK": "£1000", "US": "$1000"}` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of achieving it by using a simple key/val object for locale/price respectively:

```js
$(function() {
    var prices = {
        "UK": "£1000",
        "US": "$1500",
        "DE": "€1250"
    }

    $("[data-locale]").click(function() {
        var locale = $(this).attr("data-locale");

        // ensure the locale value is valid
        if (prices[locale]) {
            $(".price-block").text(prices[locale]);
        } else {
            $(".price-block").text("Invalid locale: " + locale);
        }
    })
})
```

```css
[data-locale] {
    border: 2px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
.price-block {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="locale-block">
    <div data-locale="UK">UK</div>
    <div data-locale="US">US</div>
    <div data-locale="DE">DE</div>
</div>

<div class="price-block"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```